# Fill in an input field through an image map area

Tags: javascript, html, image, dictionary, area

I am making an application that fills in scores for a player that plays a game in real life. A spectator keeps track of his score by clicking on what he did hit in each turn. I came across two problems:

- How do I fill in my input fields by clicking on an area.
- How do I go from turn 1 to turn 2 etc.

The image is mapped in four sectors

This is the script: ( I had an alert('test'); on the ??? space, but that didn't work either. )

```js
$("#test").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("here");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="goal" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/football_goal/football_goal_PNG24.png" usemap="#goal-map">

<map name="goal-map">
        <area id="test" href="#" alt="300 points" title="300" coords="483,50,584,146" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="300 points" title="300" coords="110,49,11,145" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="200 points" title="200" coords="13,148,110,238" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="200 points" title="200" coords="484,149,584,237" shape="rect" />
    </map> 
    <br/>
    
This is the input field that needs to be filled:

<p>Turn 1:
  <input type="text" id="turn1"></p>
<p>Turn 2:
  <input type="text" id="turn2"></p>
<p>Turn 3:
  <input type="text" id="turn3"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there - you needed to jQuerify the target:

```js
var cnt = 0;
$("#map").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cnt++;
  if (cnt > 3) {
    alert("You had your 3 gos");
  }  
  else {
    var $tgt = $(e.target);
    // console.log($tgt.attr("alt"));
    $("#turn"+cnt).val($tgt.attr("title"))
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="goal" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/football_goal/football_goal_PNG24.png" usemap="#goal-map">

<map name="goal-map" id="map">
        <area id="test" href="#" alt="300 points" title="300" coords="483,50,584,146" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="300 points" title="300" coords="110,49,11,145" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="200 points" title="200" coords="13,148,110,238" shape="rect" />
        <area class="a" href="" alt="200 points" title="200" coords="484,149,584,237" shape="rect" />
    </map> 
    <br/>
    
This is the input field that needs to be filled:

<p>Turn 1:
  <input type="text" id="turn1"></p>
<p>Turn 2:
  <input type="text" id="turn2"></p>
<p>Turn 3:
  <input type="text" id="turn3"></p>
```